# What http response to notify the client that some elements are missing in the response?

Tags: java, rest

I need to propose a http response for a client's GET. The response must say somehow that some elements in his criteria were not found. Do you have any idea how to do that ? I don't think there is a HTTP response code for it. Should I use the headers ?

Comment: You can use 400 Bad Request maybe with some custom message?

Comment: There's 404 (Not found), though that tends to be used for dead links. There's 416 (Requested Range Not Satisfiable), 412 (Precondition failed), and of course 418 (I'm a teapot). In general, you should include some additional information specific to your case in all of these.

Comment: Not really, I have to return the results that I found, plus something that says that some results are missing because they don't exist
I think the best choice is to go with the 416. Thanks @Rogue

Comment: To give you a proper advice we would need to know more about the "elements" and the "criteria" etc. Is it kind of an address that doesn't exist? Or is it more like a failing validation like the end time of a range cannot lie before the start time?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `404 Not Found` to say that it is not found and request them to try again.

Alternatively, you could use a `207 Multi-Status` and return `2xx` for the successful cases and `404` for the ones that were not successful.

It really depends on your use case.

Comment: 404 really doesn't seem to be an appropriate return code. It means the resource being requested can't be found which may not be true. It can be confusing to the client.

Comment: I think I'm gonna go with @Rogue's solution above. 416 seems to be adequate.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a custom error response body, in which you can include the detailed message for the client. For example you could have a JSON object as a response where you include the details as follows:

```json
{
    "message": "some elements in your criteria were not found",
    "elements": "A, B, C, D"
}
```

If you can be more specific about the case and give some details on what exactly are the cases for sending such a response we could help you out with the implementation.

You could assist the response with `400 Bad Request`, as the missing details can be related to a bad request.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Rogue's response, I think the status code 416(Requested Range Not Satisfiable) seems closer to what I'm looking for.

Comment: No, please don't use that. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_client_errors) and [RFC 2616](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-10.4.17) this code is not intended for your usecase, but for a very specific case in byte ranges.